# ¿ Como saber si una fecha existe entre dos meses?

Tags: sql, sybase

como puedo saber en SQL Sysbase si "22-12-1994" esta entre septiembre y diciembre

Comment: `select datepart(month, '19941222') in (9,10,11,12)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select  CASE WHEN MONTH(cast('19941222' as date)) BETWEEN 9 AND 12 THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END as EstaEntreSeptiembreYDiciembre
```